# Should I buy larger hard drives for XenServer 7.0's partitioning or stay with the legacy 6.x partitioning?

Tags: xenserver

I have a pool of XenServers that I am upgrading to 7.0. I have been doing fresh installs to switch to the new 46 GB partitioning layout, but unfortunately some of these servers only have 32GB SSD drives for root. I would like to know if anyone has had any negative experiences with 7.0 and the 4G/4G partition layout, otherwise I will probably skip the long trip to the data center at this time and proceed with the upgrades.

If I opt to not replace the 32GB drives with larger ones at this time, will I run into any serious issues with v7.0? (4GB vs 18GB for `/` makes me wonder if Citrix will be making plans to use that additional 14GB I won't have.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Run the xenserver 7 installer and choose Upgrade.  This will keep your existing 4 GB root partition.
   Pro-No new hardware purchase needed
   Con-Only 4GB root partition, and that's not really enough.  Once Patches come out, and logs flow a bit, then you'll be short on disk space.
2. Buy and install new larger disks.
   Pro-You get the larger disk space up front and no need to mess about.
   Con-There's the cost of drives.

Overall you're being short sighted by not installing larger disks now.  If its a cost thing (I know this feeling well)  then SSDs are absolutely not required in a xenserver.

Personally I have 72GB 2.5" SAS spinning disks in my home servers, and I'm using 3.3GB.  However at work I have much busier servers, and they are using anything from 3 to 6 GB of local disk space.  That's with only two patches installed to 7.2... and based on what we know from XS6.5, patches build up over time.